# "What is" command in Mathematica

Tags: syntax

I'm looking for "What is" command in Mathematica. For example, the command WhatIs[function[x]] gives a definition of the function given anywhere in the notebook or generally in kernel.

Could anyone please tell me whether this command exist?

Comment: Take a look at `Information` and friends. And maybe ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions``

Comment: If your question is meant also in the OOP context, `Head` might be also something to look for.

Comment: See also `?` and `??`

Comment: Just use `?` and `??`